# what could be better for respect the MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

what could be better for respect the MVC?

make a view with a for loop like this:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post){
            echo '<div class="post">'.$post.'</div>';
      }
?>
```

where $posts hold all the body of the post.

or in the controler make something like this:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post){
          $html = $html + '<div class="post">'.$post.'</div>';
      }
?>
```

then pass the $html to the view and display them.

Comment: If you were to properly follow the MVC paradigm, the view would be a pre-made static html page, the controller would be all-javascript and fetch and fill in DOM elements by sending ajax requests to the model (= php script).

Comment: @kentverger , I get a feeling that you are confusing views with templates there. This is why you end up with this confusion, because you don't have where to put UI logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple logic such as loops are acceptable in views, you don't want any business logic in there.  Since the logic of this loop is for display purposes, I would use the first.

Generally in template files, the foreach: endforeach syntax is used.

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post):?>
     <div class="post"><?php echo $post;?></div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Or if short tags are enabled  (Please note that this is often disabled on production servers, but <?php cannot be disabled, so I'd recommend the above method):

```
<? foreach($posts as $post):?>
     <div class="post"><?=$post?></div>
<? endforeach;?>
```

However this is a convention as opposed to a rule.

Comment: thaks a lot, i wil use the first one

Answer (score 1):

The first. The controller should never involve itself in presentation. If you have too much logic in a view, move it into a viewhelper/component/widget.

Comment: ok, i just have this little question, in some where i hear that the controller must control ¬¬ all the things in the view. Thanks a lot

Comment: @blockhead, while I agree with your diagnosis, the treatment is kinda wrong. View is not supposed to be a dumb template (contrary to what rapid prototyping frameworks popularized). Also ... sorry for resurrecting an ancient post.